# Calculating Skewness and kurtosis with apache commons

Tags: java, math, statistics, apache-commons

I have datapoints in a vector and I would like to calculate the skewness and kurtosis of the dataset.

How do I go about this with apache commons?

```
Vector<Double> mydata = new Vector<Double>
//data points are added by my routing
```

The code I found in the documentation goes like this:

```
    FourthMoment m4 = new FourthMoment();
    Mean m = new Mean(m4);
    Variance v = new Variance(m4);
    Skewness s= new Skewness(m4);
    Kurtosis k = new Kurtosis(m4);
    assertEquals(var,v.getResult(),tolerance);
    assertEquals(skew ,s.getResult(),tolerance);
```

But Fourthmoment is not recognised by my compiler. And how do I actually get the mydata in there?

Thanks for any help, I can not seem to get clear examples.

I use version 3.1.1 and it recognises all my imports, except the first one:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.moment.FourthMoment;
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.moment.Kurtosis;
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.moment.Mean;
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.moment.Skewness;
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.moment.Variance;
```

Comment: It should recognize FourthMoment.  What version of apache commons is it?

Comment: 3.1.1, I just downloaded it. It recognises all my imports, but not the first one (I edited the question)

Comment: Not seeing a class with this name in http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.1.1/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/moment/package-summary.html

Comment: do I need this fourth moment? Or can I just calculate it based on my vector?

Comment: @NPE Yeah, it's weird, ThirdMoment isn't there either, just SecondMoment.  The javadoc for 3.1.1 does have references to it in the Kurtosis description and even in the code listing, but it's not showing as a class entry in the doc.

Comment: Other library suggestions then? Or should I just write a function myself?

Comment: @dorien Have you tried bringing in the whole moment package?

Comment: `evaluate()` should work.  Other than that, you could just cut and paste the routine listings from the current and older doc.

Comment: @RBarryYound, yes I have tried import org.apache.commons.math3.*; But does recognise the function.

Comment: Hoe do I need to use evaluate? How do I get my data in the right variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> do I need this fourth moment? Or can I just calculate it based on my vector?

I think you can calculate it directly, using [`Kurtosis.evaluate()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.1.1/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/moment/Kurtosis.html#evaluate%28double%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).